# How do I make an array method return a single object when the array length is 1?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I have a method within a class I created. Each object of the class has the property of having an an Object array, and the method returns that array. However, is there a way for me to just return the single Object from within the array when the array length is 1?

Comment: please [provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far

Answer (score 4):

**You can't.** If a method is declared to return `Object[]`, you can't return an `Object`. The types aren't compatible.

**But you don't want to, either.** It's a common anti-pattern to return `null` from methods that return collections. It's better to return an empty collection, that way the caller doesn't have to check for `null`. They can just iterate over the empty collection. Almost always the code will do the right thing anyways.

This simple loop...

```
for (int n: getNumbers()) {
    performCalculation(n);
}
```

...becomes this inelegant mess:

```
int[] numbers = getNumbers();

if (numbers != null) {
    for (int n: numbers) {
        performCalculation(n);
    }
}
```

Similarly, even if it were possible, special casing a single element would make the caller's job more complicated. They'd have to check if they got a collection or a single object and branch.